# Query failed --- select count(*) with order by got sqlserver error 8127

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have some data in TableA like below

```
ID  TIME                    VAL
1   2020-10-01 12:00:12.000 test
2   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
3   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
4   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
5   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
6   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
7   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
8   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
9   2020-10-01 13:00:12.000 test2
```

I want to count the data with order by time and limit offset, I tried like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableA
WHERE TIME>'2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND TIME<'2020-10-01 23:59:59'
ORDER BY TIME ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

but I get an error

> Column "TableA.TIME" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Executed the query under SQL Server 2012

how to make it right?

**the result why i do this process**

I want count one page's records and check as if equals the page size. then decide to query the real data again and cache them.

suppose the data has been added by time one by one, i want count then data with page by page, suppose one page include 50 records. so at first i have to order by time asc, then get the count of target page by 'offset limit', while the count is equals the redis cached data's count, i will get the data from redis, if not, which means these is some new data inserted, i will get the data from db, then cache the new count and new data into redis again.
all the data should be order by time asc with pagenation,which means the last page's count will change,so i need do such query to check the actural count of one page.

Comment: Can you mention the desired resultset ?

Comment: Please describe what you want.  Without description, how do you think people can help you???  Your query doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Please read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're asking it to order by a column that isn't in your select statement. The select, as is, will only return the count(*) value. If you add the time column to your select, or change your order by to say "ORDER BY 1", then your query should work, but as stated, I'm not sure exactly what results you're trying to get.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i added the reason why i need this query. i think it is reasonable to do like that.is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    from(
    select *
    FROM TableA
    WHERE TIME>'2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND TIME<'2020-10-01 23:59:59'
    ORDER BY TIME ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
    ) as x
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. sqlserver is not as easy as mysql :(

Answer (score 0):

The start of your query makes us think that you want to get a single output which is a count of all the items in your table between the two dates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableA
WHERE TIME>'2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND TIME<'2020-10-01 23:59:59'
```

But the rest of the query makes us think that you want to get the first 50 elements of the filtered elements:

```
ORDER BY TIME ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

If you want to count, keep only the first part:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableA
WHERE Time BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-01 23:59:59'
```

If you want to get the results, remove the count:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Time BETWEEN '2020-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-01 23:59:59'
ORDER BY TIME ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i added the reason why i need this query. i think it is reasonable to do like that.is it?